# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Theme#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo este error al intentar pasar  parametros por `link_to`  hacia otro controlador:

**Models**

```
class Theme < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :themes
end
```

**Controller**

```
def new
  @theme=@category.themes.new
  @themes=@category.themes
end
```

**HTML**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Rutas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Routes.rb**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item.id` te regresa valor `nil` (i.e. no se ha asignado `id` aún), por lo tanto obtienes el error:

> missing required keys: [:theme_id]

Para solucionarlo verifica que el objeto `item` sea guardado antes; lo más probable es que hayas generado el objeto `@category` y hayas asignado los `themes` sin guardar el objeto principal (i.e. con `@category.new`) y, por lo tanto, el `id` aún no se ha generado por lo que tiene valor `nil`.

Corrigiendo mi respuesta anterior, el *helper* `new_category_theme_comment_path` **si** puede recibir parámetros como *hash* y como objetos de `ActiveRecord` (ademas de números), por lo tanto cualquiera de las siguientes opciones es válida:

```
<!-- con hash -->
<%= link_to “show”, new_category_theme_comment_path(item.category_id, theme_id: item.id) %>

<!-- con número -->
<%= link_to “show”, new_category_theme_comment_path(item.category_id, item.id) %>

<!-- con objeto AR -->
<%= link_to “show”, new_category_theme_comment_path(item.category_id, item) %>
```

Comment: Hola Gerry ,thank  por comentar ; ahora obtengo este error , No route matches {:action=>"new", :category_id=>"2", :controller=>"comment", :theme_id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:theme_id]

Comment: @Gerson Parece ser que `item.id` no tiene valor asignado (i.e. es `nil`); he actualizado la respuesta para darte más detalle (y corregir mi afirmación anterior, que era incorrecta).